# Mysql PrefPane not working - OS X

Tags: mysql, macos, osx-lion

When I try to start MySQL from the PrefPane, it asks me for my password and then it keeps saying MySQL Server has `stopped` in red.

It doesn't start.

```
$ mysqladmin start
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock' exists!
$ mysql start
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

When I search processes for `mysql`, this is what I see:

```
$ ps wwaux | grep mysqld | grep -v grep
_mysql           203   0.0  0.5  2518204  19288   ??  S     3:30PM   0:23.25 /opt/local/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/opt/local --datadir=/opt/local/var/db/mysql5 --user=_mysql --log-error=/opt/local/var/db/mysql5/localhost.err --pid-file=/opt/local/var/db/mysql5/localhost.pid --socket=/tmp/mysql.sock --port=3306
root              75   0.0  0.0  2435492    884   ??  S     3:30PM   0:00.04 /bin/sh /opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/opt/local/var/db/mysql5 --pid-file=/opt/local/var/db/mysql5/localhost.pid
```

Thoughts?

Comment: This question was better suited for "SuperUser" not Stack Overflow, which is more for programming questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out, that a `mysqld` process was running and got stalled. So I just went into `Activity Monitor` and killed it, and restarted it.

It now works.

Answer (score 0):

Check if MySQL port is open:

```
telnet localhost 3306
```

Check whether mysql.sock file exists and fix its permissions if necessary:

```
sudo chown _mysql:wheel /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Try to stop and start MySQL via Terminal:

```
sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM stop
sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM start
```

If nothing helps, try to reset MySQL root password and/or reinstall MySQL.

Comment: Nah..was something dumb. It seems a `mysql` process was running, so I had to kill it first...then restarted it and it works. I have added this as an answer.

Comment: marcamillion, thanks for that. Totally forgot to check to see if the process was already there. Helped out a bunch :)